# Inconsistent single- and double-clicks in GNOME/GTK file manager

Tags: files, gtk

I mostly use KDE programs and just use the Awesome WM as window manager. There the KDE/Qt file dialog works with single clicks everywhere. A single click will enter into directory and also select a file.

A GNOME/GTK file dialog like I get with `gnome-boxes` or Firefox behaves rather inconsistent. To enter the first directory, I have to double-click, a single-click will only select. Then the next single-click will already enter into the next directory or select the file and close the dialog.

I find this behavior rather upsetting. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: It's a pretty nasty bug. And while there are some solutions available everybody seems to be waiting for a design decision on the matters. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758065

Comment: The only course of action that will change something quickly seems to just avoid all programs with a GTK file dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNOME team has finally reverted that strange single-click behavior, so this is fixed after years of discussion.

Comment: Indeed, this appears to have been fixed in version 3.22.29 by [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/commit/f0d5b956) commit, but I haven't tested it.